# New Column for each subset

Tags: sql, postgresql

In this example I want to call all rows of a table. However, contents of the table can be found again in subsets. Look:

I have a small database of footballers that is built like this:

Player: [PID, Name, Number]

Goalkeeper: [PID]

Defender: [PID, Side]

Midfielder: [PID, Specialty]

Attacker: [PID, StrongFoot]

So what I am trying to do is, instead of having one column for player.name, I want the Names of Goalkeepers, Defenders, Midfielders and Attackers in separate columns. What I've tried to do for starters is:

```
select distinct gk.name, def.name 
from (select p.name
from player p, goalkeeper g 
where p.pid = g.pid) gk, (select p.name
from player p, defender d 
where p.pid = d.pid) def
```

But this gives me several results (at best). So each entry is for, say, a goalkeeper is repeated as often as the number of def.name in total.

What would be an acceptable/ GOOD way of doing this?

EDIT:

So, to expound on my problem:

Say I have 2 Goalkeepers in my Database {"GK1", "GK2"} and 6 defenders {"D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6"}. If I run the query above, I get two columns but instead of having 2 and 6 entries respectively, I get 12 for each. In the Goalkeeper one, each ID is repeated 6 times, in the Defender column each entry is repeated 2 times. Is there a way to just display the distinct values (so mentioning each ID just once) in each column and setting the other NULL?

Comment: Why is the column `Name` again in the related tables `Goalkeeper`, `Defender`, `Midfielder`, `Attacker`? Sounds like redundancy to me. If the values do not match, then which one is the correct one?

Comment: Let me check again, I may have copied this wrong.

Comment: Can you give an example of your anticipated results?  I'm not fully clear on what you're desiring.  Is it a concatenated list of names in each column with one row for each position?

Comment: Database design should maintain one *Players* table and a *Positions* table in a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want four separate columns with the players, instead of a single player column. You can do it using four "left outer joins", as in:

```
select
  p.pid,
  case when g.pid is not null then p.name end as goalkeeper,
  case when d.pid is not null then p.name end as defender,
  case when m.pid is not null then p.name end as midfielder,
  case when a.pid is not null then p.name end as attacker
from player p
left join goalkeeper g on g.pid = p.pid
left join defender d on d.pid = p.pid
left join midfieldfer m on m.pid = p.pid
left join attacker a on a.pid = p.pid
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you very much!
Edit: select distinct makes it look better though.

Comment: Why would you need `DISTINCT`? I thought `player`.`pid` was the primary key of the table (it won't allow duplicates by definition).

Comment: You're right, I made a typo querying on my part, which I then later discovered. sorry